# magento - Unable to communicate with the PayPal gateway

Tags: magento, paypal

Is there any solution for this? I have already disabled SSL verification at configuration >> system >> payment methods >> PayPal payment solutions. But still not working..

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem, including exact error message, Magento version, and which PayPal integration you have enabled and whether it is live or sandbox.

Comment: Error Message : Unable to communicate with the paypal gateway. Magento Version: 1.7 and I am using Paypal Express Checkout and is in live mode.

Comment: It was working before but it just stopped working. Below are the changes I made to the files.

1)tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml
2)enabled frontend to use SSH.

I have already revert back the changes but still its not working. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to check your Paypal settings and credentials, if possible please Paypal using Sandbox credentials first, then use live credentials. you can this also-http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-for-your-magento-store

Answer (score 20):

You need to disable SSL verification. Go to the back-end, System-> Configuration-> Payment Methods and find PayPal Express Checkout. Click on the "configure" button, expand "advanced settings" and there you'll see "Enable SSL verification" option that you need to disable - turn it to "No".

P.S. If you get the same error after this actions, try to disable your Anti-virus.

Comment: If this works for you, then it is not a permanent solution, but a workaround. The correct thing to do is to figure out **why** verification fails. By disabling it, you lose **all** of the security of SSL, since an attacker can set up a fake server to spoof the real one, along with setting up a rogue DNS server, to redirect requests to their fake server